# Does Heimdall verify compatibility?

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, heimdall

I want to flash TWRP to my Samsung Android device. I do not know if there is a compatible version of TWRP (device model not listed).

Does Heimdall verify compatibility before flashing with `sudo heimdall flash --RECOVERY twrp.img`?

Comment: How should Heimdall know which image is compatible or not?

Comment: I don't have any evidence for this other than personal use, so I am not listing it as an answer, but the answer is no... Heimdall or Odin does NOT verify anything, if you tell it to flash something and it's the wrong thing, it will happily do so and any ramifications from that are purely on you, which could be just a flash of the correct one or a complete bricking of the device. There is no safeguard to protect you in Heimdall, so make sure you know exactly what you are doing.